# how to insert this text in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

i want to insert some text in mysql but text have double quote `""` in middle of the text then insert query failed what i do in c# to solve this issue

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\x85\xE0\xA4\xAD...' for column 'colname' at row 1

ex: this is a simple "text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query parameters. For example:

```
sql.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?UserName", username);
sql.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Password", password);
sql.command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?UserName
  AND `password`=?Password LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

use the escape character ('\') to escape the quotes so they can be interpreted literally.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `\` char to escape the quotes. So instead of `"` you will have `\"`. For a longer, more realistic example, you might have something like:

`"This string has quotes around \"this phrase\" but they are part of the value"`